# Magic.Net with GhostScript converting eps to svg is blank in illustrator

Tags: c#, imagemagick, adobe-illustrator, magicknet

```
Windows 10 home 64bit.
```

I have very small app in c# which should convert `.eps` to `.svg`.
`Using Magic.Net-Q16-AnyCPU` as a `nuget` also installed on windows GhostScript `gs952w32.exe`.

Function for conversion:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(@"C:\folder1\1.eps"))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Svg;
    image.Write(@"C:\folder2\1.svg");
}
```

image is converted and also I can open it via some browsers websites which can read svg.
But when I try it open with illustrator it shows an error 
`"Could not find the linked file ''. Choose replace to select another file or Ignore to leave the link unchanged."` 
And after opening an image is empty.

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't produce SVG so I don't think this can be anythign to do with Ghostscript. The image application must be taking the rendered output from Ghostscript and producing a SVG from the bitmap.

Comment: @KenS, MagicNet using Ghostscript for opening eps files.

Comment: I'm sure it is, I said as much, but it must be taking the output from Ghostscript and doing something else to it to make an SVG, as Ghostscript does not produce svg. Now if you can show that the intermediate file produced by Ghostscript is wrong then I'm more than happy to accept this as a Ghostscript problem, but he production of the SVG (which iis where the problem seems to lie) is not done by Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [github thread on Magic.Net](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/discussions/610)

It seems that Illustrator does not support embeded PNG files.
ImageMagick/Magick.NET is probably not the best tool to convert from EPS to SVG. The image will be changed from a vector format to a raster image.